Localized icon in android
I am trying to implement the following functionality: when the devices language is Polish, one icon is used, with any other language - another.
I have mipmap folders created for different screen densities in my project:

And the same folder but for Polish (mipmap-pl-hdpi, mipmap-pl-mdpi, etc).
I generated the existing icons via android asset studio. However, when I try to generate files for Polish locale the same way, I can't choose their destination:

How do I create the icons for a specific locale via android asset studio?

My guess is that you will need to back up the one set of images, generate the second set, move them into your desired directories, then restore the original set of images.

As @CommonsWare suggested, the easiest way is to generate them one by one, put them in their desired folder, then regenerate for other locale. Thats what I do when I need to have different icons for different variants.
